# Is it a possible to add a stakeholder to an impact map?

Tags: agile, product-management, stakeholders

My team and I were considering adding a stakeholder actor to the map, but we've got questions.

First, if we have it in the map, how can we fill the 4th field, i.e. how can we affect our stakeholder?

Second, impact maps are intended to be presented to a stakeholder, does it make sense to have the stakeholder in there?

Follow [this link](https://www.impactmapping.org/assets/impact_mapping_20121001_sample.pdf) for more info on impact mapping (found in google)

Comment: Hi Radical, welcome to PM.SE! I'm not familiarised with Impact Mappings, and googling this it seems to be a technique used to identify the stakeholders for a given product. Would that be the case? If that's the case, then would be good to tag the question with [tag:product-management] tag.

Comment: Hi Tiago, impact maps are more about communication with your stakeholder, I am not sure though. Still, product-management tag suits well here. Thank you!

Comment: It would be really useful to add a link to something that would teach us about impact maps.

Comment: I second @MarkC.Wallace comment - this seems to be a nice opportunity to learn something new, and a way to give more context to your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no harm in adding them and seeing if you can come up with any impact or deliverable. You can always take them off later if it turns out that they don't actually want anything. Or, you can even leave them on their for when you show them to say "we don't really understand what you're getting out of this".

In my experience, it is great to have anyone who is on the impact map take a look at it. When it's you putting the info on there, it's just an assumption. Having the actual actor look at it helps validate that assumption.

Answer (score 0):

For a B2C business, the impact map is more for the external customer.
For a B2B business, the impact map can be for your internal customers(stakeholders).

It depends on the area of ownership you have for the product.